# Mysql query taking too much time to load on production of AWS server

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I am new on AWS RDS

I have testing server on AWS EC2 instance and Mysql is also installed into same instance. In this test server application working good way BUT

After all done we are moved application on production instance and for production we are using RDS DB Instance to use Mysql.

**Problem is**
PHP and RDS Mysql connection successfull but when we try to load page (having more than 10000 rows of mysql) taking too much time to load page.

I used simple query for getting data eg.

```
select 
    (column_names with , comma) 
from 
    tabel_name t 
left join table_name2 t2 on t2.id=t.id 
where 
   t2.id = '1' and 
   t.type='PROD'
```

same query working good way on other EC2 instance and inbuilt mysql.

**AWS RDS Details**
[Screenshot of RDS details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X99k8.png)

EC2 instance available zone is Availability zone
ap-south-1av and RDS DB's zone is Availability zone
ap-south-1b

Please help me out of this.
TIA,

Comment: What does [`EXPLAIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) say about the query when run from dev and production?

Comment: How many rows does your query expect to return. You said 'more than 10,000' -- is it 100,000? is it 1,000,000? 10M? And what does 'too long to load' mean? 10 seconds? minutes? hours? How much data is being pulled from the database when you're running the query? Are your network bound? etc.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you have proper index  on the columns involved in join

be sure that the id is a string otherwise don't use quote  (this normally implies the not use of index)

```
select (column_names with , comma) 
from tabel_name t 
left join table_name2 t2 on t2.id=t.id 
where t2.id = 1 and t.type='PROD'
```

( load 10000 rows  seems difficulty useful in a pratical application )

Comment: Yes, i have set indexes. i have try with same things without RDS instance into other EC2 Test server (in this i have install mysqld)